# Sitemesh or XSLT for layout

Tags: xslt, sitemesh

I am designing a layout for my crm project now.

Now i am ended with 2 options one is sitemesh to define the layout or XSLT to define a layout.

Sitemesh will run at runtime from the server , it wont cause any issue if the number of request is high?

I guess XSLT will run at the browser based on the Xpath , is this correct?

Which one is better to use?

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run XSLT either in the browser or at the server.  The advantage to running it at the server is that the HTML you generate will be the same regardless of what browser the user has.  If you run it in the web browser, users with different browsers might get slightly different results, because different XSLT transformation engines have different quirks, kind of like different web browsers do when rendering the same HTML and CSS.

I've designed and taught a corporate 1-day intro to XSLT class. I love the way XSLT works.  That said, it has been criticized for running slowly and being hard to learn.

I've just started using SiteMesh 2.0, and I really like it.  If you are not familiar with XSLT coding, you may be more comfortable with SiteMesh, because it simply wraps your content with a header/footer you create.  You don't have to write and debug XSLT code.